# WsOutbound close function causes Tomcat to crash

Tags: tomcat, websocket

I've implemented a websocket connection in Tomcat 7, with a javascript client.
It works nicely, except for one scenario: when I open several connections one after the other (by refreshing the client) and then closing all connections, the Tomcat crashes.
after debugging, I found out that the function that makes the Tomcat crash is the close() function of the WsOutbound object.
Here is my code: 

try {
m_tickMesageInbound.getWsOutbound().close(0, null);
} catch (IOException e) {
logger.debug("Error while closing output");
}

(m_tickMesageInbound is an object that extends MessageInbound)
I have a theory that the connection that I am trying to close is already closed, thus causing an error, but there is no interface to check this.
I've tried overriding the onClosed() function in the messageInbound class, and setting the code to skip the closing function if it happens, but that didn't help.
It is important to note that the Tomcat crashes completely, i.e. goes offline, leaving no log to explain the problem. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Did you already found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you try to close with this code: m_tickMesageInbound.getWsOutbound().close(0, ByteBuffer.allocate(0));

Answer (score 0):

> leaving no log to explain the problem

You can find the hs_err.log in the tomcat/bin folder. This will help you to debug the issue further.