# Tomcat 7 crashes on websocket close in Safari (not in Firefox)

Tags: java, tomcat, crash, websocket

I have the same problem as in [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671046/wsoutbound-close-function-causes-tomcat-to-crash)

Cannot find a solution. In my setup it works fine with Firefox, but not in Safari or Chrome. The whole Tomcat server goes down...

Comment: If whole tomcat goes down it sounds like a JVM crash.  Check for crash reports.  You may have to start it manually to get it.  Also check you run on the latest release of your java flavor.

Comment: What do the logs say?  "The whole Tomcat server goes down ..." is not sufficient information for a diagnosis.

Comment: Here is the URL to the full log message of the crash. It is indeed a JVM crash: [log file](http://www.craenhals.eu/logs/hs_err_pid2396.log)

Comment: Anybody that knows a solution?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am encountering the same problem.

Comment: The only thing I have tried for the moment is stopped using the native Tomcat libraries. Since then the problem didn't occurred anymore.

Comment: I have also seen that Apache has released a new Tomcat version 7.0.39 where the problem should have been fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately that is the version that I'm using. Which Tomcat libraries are you using?